# SwiftUI: Cannot change view's size using gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This seems trivial, but I cannot use `DragGesture` to change the view's size. The `onChanged` callback is being called infinitely with "random" values and freezes the app. `onEnded` is never called. This happens when I try to offset a view as well, but only when the gesture is attached to a subview. Changing size happens for all cases. If I set an animation to the size change, it won't freeze the app, but the translation is smaller than it should be.

```
struct ResizableView: View {

  @State private var size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
  @State private var initialSize: CGSize?

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Color.red

      VStack {
        HStack {
          Color.blue
            .frame(width: 16, height: 16)
            .gesture(
              resizeDragGesture
            )
          Spacer()
        }
        Spacer()
      }
    }
    .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    // Adding the line below will not halt the app, but the translation value is not correct anymore
//    .animation(.default, value: size)
  }

  private var resizeDragGesture: some Gesture {
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
      .onChanged { value in
        guard let initialSize = initialSize else {
          initialSize = size
          return
        }

        size = CGSize(
          width: max(100, initialSize.width - value.translation.width),
          height: max(100, initialSize.height - value.translation.height)
        )
      }
      .onEnded { _ in
        initialSize = nil
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: The TL;DR of the attached question is that you need `coordinateSpace: .local` when you are moving a view with a drag gesture

Comment: You're the man. Works perfectly. Silly me, totally missed that `coodinateSpace` param.